# Spring resource handler on classpath jar

Tags: java, spring

I need to access static files from one library, but it's not working.

The following code finds and prints the required file:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void checkResources() {
        try {
            for (Resource r : ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources("classpath*:**/reports/*"))
            {
                Utils.log(r.getURL());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> jar:file:/C:/../mydependency.jar!/reports/reports.js

But adding resource handlers using the same pattern does not work:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/reports/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/reports", "classpath*:**/reports")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Javadoc of [`addResourceLocations(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistration.html#addResourceLocations-java.lang.String...-) says: *"Each location must point to a valid directory."* --- This means that **wildcards are not supported**. Which makes sense, because what if you had resources `/a/reports/foo.js` and `/b/reports/foo.js`, then which would be served to a request for `/reports/foo.js`? --- Change to `"classpath:/reports/"`

Comment: Ok. I had tried that and other combinations already and it does not work.